# PHP - extracting key values from a $_POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

In my $_POST array, I have the following values:

```
[txtPe_20_Table1] => 2.3
[txtPa_12_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPa_25_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPa_35_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPa_50_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPa_100_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPa_200_Table1] => 0.00
[txtPr_12_Table1] => 0.00
```

Now, what I want to do is extract only the number values from the keys starting with 'txtPa_'.

What would be the best approach to do this? Should I use regex or just loop through the array searching for a substr beginning with 'txtPa_'?

Comment: i would change the form to group txtPa together in to an array. otherwise a foreach loop and look at the key

Answer (score 3):

while it would be best to structure the form so you get the keys grouped together. if you can't then you can do this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$var){
  if(substr($key, 0, 6)=='txtPa_'){
  //so something with $var
  }
}
```

from @Rizier123

```
$filtered = array_filter(function($k){ return strpos($k, "txtPa_") === 0; },ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

form change option

..

```
<input type="text" name="txtPa[12_Table1]">
<input type="text" name="txtPa[25_Table1]">
```

etc
then you have the array `$_POST[txtPa]`

Comment: Or simple an [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) call with the flag for keys :) (PHP >=5.6)

Comment: If you want to add it to your answer: `$filtered = array_filter(function($k){
  return strpos($k, "txtPa_") === 0;
 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); `